# display datepicker on dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm trying to show datepicker when user click on dynamically created button.i don't want to show text box there so i use hidden input.

Javascript:

```
        function showDate(){
        var dateDiv = $('#dateDiv');
        for(ind=0; ind<=5; ind++){
            var date = $('<img src="calendar.png" class="datepicker" id="'+ind+'-date" /><input type="hidden" id="'+ind+'-date-picker" /><br />');
            dateDiv.append(date);
        }
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        showDate();
        $('.datepicker').live('click', function(){
            var datepickerId =$(this).attr('id');
            datepickerId += '-picker';
            $('#'+datepickerId).datepicker();
        });
    }
```

but nothing happen when i click on calender icon.

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="dateDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.datepicker()` just sets up a datepicker. You may do this already when you create the div, and not every time it is clicked.

To show it, you may call `.datepicker('show');`

Comment: there are dynamically created buttons.how can i set up datepicker for each hidden input field. @david

Comment: You're setting them up alright, but I'd do it where they are created rather than where you want them to be shown. No biggie; the important thing is the call to 'show' to display the actual picker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of JQuery you are using, but if it is 1.7+ '.live()' is deprecated and if it is 1.9+ it has been removed. [Link](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Additionally, I would suggest using the document.ready function to initialize.

```
function showDate(){
    var dateDiv = $('#dateDiv');
    for(ind=0; ind<=5; ind++){
         var date = $('<img src="calendar.png" class="datepicker" id="'+ind+'-date" /><input type="hidden" id="'+ind+'-date-picker" /><br />');
        dateDiv.append(date);
    }
}

$(document).ready( function(){
    showDate();

    $('.datepicker').on('click', function(){
        var $datepicker =$(this).attr('id');
        $datepicker += '-picker';
        $('#'+$datepicker).datepicker();
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/jsNbU/1/)